# How to make black slides with IPE?

Tags: ipe

I'm trying to get white text on a black background in my slides with IPE.

So far I've tried to add the *shading* element in the presentation.isy stylesheet, from page 29 of (quite old) [The IPE Manual](http://www.math.sinica.edu.tw/www/tex/IPE_manual.pdf)), but it seems outdated: even the example on page 19 rises an error when I try to add the stylesheet. However, even getting *shading* to work could be a bad solution: the manual says that the shading only appears in the generated pdf, while in the editor the pages keep being white, so I would have to deal with white text on a white background during the editing...

I've also tried the naive approach of setting the titles color to white and covering the whole page with a black-filled square, but then the title is not visible even if I move the square in the background. Of course I could manually write each title with a white label/minipage, but there should be some more proper way...

Comment: Please give us an MWE to play around with.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi it is not clear to me what a MWE should be here. I'm asking how can I produce some result, and I have no idea of the correct way to do it. I could produce a MWE about my first attempt, but I'm unsure that that solution would be the one I'm looking for. I'll edit that paragraph explaining why.

Comment: Of course we like to see what you have tried but especially we do not like to set up a test document for you. The very basic framework should be in your post in order to get copied and tested by us.

Comment: That's the manual for ipe 6.  You want the manual for ipe 7.